# Connecting a Project ID to polygon

Tags: javascript, blockchain, polygon, solidity, hardhat

What am i doing wrong/missing? When trying to connect my project's id from https://infura.io/ I am getting the following error after running:

```
$  npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network mumbai
```

error:

ProviderError: project ID does not have access to polygon l2

here is my file

```js
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");
require("dotenv").config();
const privateKey = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;
const projectId = process.env.PROJECT_ID;

if (privateKey.error) {
  throw privateKey.error;
}

if (projectId.error) {
  throw projectId.error;
}

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      chainId: 1337,
    },
    mumbai: {
      url: `https://polygon-mumbai.infura.io/v3/${projectId}`,
      accounts: [privateKey],
    },
    mainnet: {
      url: `https://arbitrum-mainnet.infura.io/v3/${projectId}`,
      accounts: [privateKey],
    },
    matic: {
      url: "https://rpc-mainnet.maticvigil.com",
      accounts: [privateKey],
    },
  },
  solidity: "0.8.4",
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I figured it out, turned out I needed to enable polygon beta inside my account settings and add my billing information for infura.io

Comment: can you help me? same problem

Comment: Yeah check out the settings in the dashboard. You need to toggle the feature

Answer (score 0):

Alchemy - https://dashboard.alchemyapi.io/ is an alternative to interact with Polygon network. No need for billing information